# CALayer overlaps top layer after transformation

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, calayer, transformation

I have two CALayers each showing an image. The first (left) layer in the view hierarchy is on top of the second one. The problem is that after I apply a rotation around the y-axis, the right layer is all of a sudden drawn above the layer that's supposed to be on top.

I tried using different zPosition values. Nothing. My other guess was that maybe the animation of the right layer finishes *after* the animation for the left layer and hence it is drawn on top. To test this, I applied the transformation for the right layer first, but still the same result. Oh, I also tried CA transactions without any luck.

Here a screenshot:

[image: the problem]

What is the correct way to animate a number of CALayers while keeping their order?

Thanks, Mark.
EDIT:

Here is the code for the transformation. I tried disabling the animation, but got the same result.

```
[CATransaction begin];

[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue
                 forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];

CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / 400;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, DegreesToRadians(70), 0, 1, 0);

 for(CALayer *layer in [self.layer sublayers]) {
    // transform the two layers
    layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;

}
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: I assume that this is after making the change discussed in the previous question to move the perspective transforms into the individual layers, right? When you say that you tried different zPositions, do you mean that you’re assigning different zPositions to each layer?

Comment: Yes and yes. I assigned different zPositions to each layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried translating on the z axis? Either make your top layer have a larger number or your lower layer have a lower or negative number. Try something really large to start with and see if it addresses the issue. Then narrow the margin until you get the layer as close as possible without causing the shift you're seeing. Something like this:

```
CATransform3D trans = CATransform3DIdentity;
trans.m34 = 1 / -900;

trans = CATransform3DTranslate(trans, 0.0f, 0.0f, -500.0f);

[lowerLayer setTransform:trans];
```

The down side is if you're planning to stack up a bunch of layers, you would probably have to use this minimum margin and multiply that by the number of layers you're planning to display causing the stack to fade into the distance. Of course, if that's the effect you're going for, this would be a good thing.

Comment: I tried that in addition to the rotation and the layers were completely moved out of the screen. Eventually I want a row of 10 or more of these layers next to each other. Why does this effect happen in the first place? Is it a result of the animation or of the layer order?

Comment: Okay. Can you post some code in your question so we can see the transforms you're using?

Comment: Ok. So your perspective has a positive number which will cause the flipping to be in the wrong direction. Change the m34 line to rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -400; making it a negative number. For testing don't disable the animations so you can see the layers morph/animate from identity transform to your transform and you'll see what I mean. Also, you are animating/transforming *all* of the layers in your view hierarchy including your view's root layer. That's probably not what you want. I threw together a little sample project here: http://www.cimgf.com/files/LayerFlip.zip

Comment: Matt, you rock! I just came here to answer my own question after I had finally figured it out only to find your post including a working demo project. That's awesome! Thanks again. By the way, yes, it was the positive perspective value that caused the issue. The only problem left now is a flickering when the animation ends, but I'll try to sort that out myself this time :)